# How to pass numbers associated with each letter to different textboxes from a main textbox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have made a winform app which takes the values from the textboxes and pass to different textboxes.
But in my case I am able to pass the values. When I delete some letters in between I am unable to pass exactly each numbers to the specified textboxes.

I have 10 textboxes to receive values. And I have one major textbox (i.e.) textbox11 to write the values and pass them to rest 10 textboxes.

So lets say I am typing N14 G73 X315.2 Y83.7 I40.0 J6.4 A0.0 H3 K75 T11 F5 M0 C0.0 in textbox11. I can successfully pass values of

```
 N to textbox1 = 14
 G to textbox2 =73
 X to textbox3 = 315.2
 Y to textbox4 = 83.7
 I to textbox5 = 40.0
 J to textbox6 = 6.4
 H to textbox7 = 3
 K to textbox8 = 75
 F to textbox9 = 30 
 T to textbox10 = 11
```

But when I change the format to N14 G73 X315.2 Y83.7 I40.0 A0.0 H3 K75 T11 F5 M0 C0.0
So here when **compared with above line, we can see J6.4 is missing**
In this case, my values are left shifted.. 
Below is the output I am getting..

```
 N to textbox1 = 14
 G to textbox2 =73
 X to textbox3 = 315.2
 Y to textbox4 = 83.7
 I to textbox5 = 40.0
 J to textbox6 = 0.0
 H to textbox7 = 0.0
 K to textbox8 = 3
 F to textbox9 = 75
 T to textbox10 = 30
```

How to deal with this situation.. I want to take each number to each textbox individually regardless of the string length.

Code snippet:

```
    private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string originalText = textBox11.Text;
        string[] splitString = originalText.Split(new Char[] { 'N', 'G', 'X', 'Y', 'I', 'J', 'A', 'H', 'K', 'F', 'T', 'M', 'C' }); 

        foreach (String str in splitString)
        {
            if(str == null || str.Length == 0) 
        {
            switch (str[0])
            {
                case 'N':
                    textBox1.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    textBox2.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    textBox3.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                    textBox4.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    textBox5.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'J':
                    textBox6.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    textBox7.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'K':
                    textBox8.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    textBox9.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    textBox10.Text = str.Substring(1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want the prepended character describe where that number is going? So, `N14` should put `14` in `textBox1` no matter where it is in the string?

Comment: @Gutblender If that's the case, then there's an inconsistency with the letter F in the example. `F5` translates to `F = 30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The final version:
For the particular question, its better to use regular expression. . Here is the optimized code:

```
    private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string originalText = textBox11.Text;
        string[] splitString = originalText.Split(new Char[] { 'N', 'G', 'X', 'Y', 'I', 'J', 'A', 'H', 'K', 'F', 'T', 'M', 'C' });

        String charset = "NGXYIJHKFT";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[NGXYIJAHKTFMC]\d*\.?\d*");
        String str = "";

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(originalText))
        {
            str = match.Value;

            Control[] controls = Controls.Find("textBox" + (charset.IndexOf(str[0]) + 1), true);

            if (controls.Length > 0)
                ((TextBox)controls[0]).Text = str.Substring(1);                
        }


    }
```

======
Older answers..

You better split by space and then while setting into textboxes you can remove the first character.
The reason is split by multiple characters cannot ensure the order by which they will come into the output array.

```
private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string originalText = textBox11.Text;
    string[] splitString = originalText.Split(new Char[] { 'N', 'G', 'X', 'Y', 'I', 'J', 'A', 'H', 'K', 'F', 'T', 'M', 'C' }); 


foreach(String str in splitString)
{
    if(str == null || str.Length == 0) 
       continue;

    switch(str[0])
    {
        case 'N':
            textBox1.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'G':
            textBox2.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'X':
            textBox3.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'Y':
            textBox4.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'I':
            textBox5.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'J':
            textBox6.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'H':
            textBox7.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'K':
            textBox8.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'F':
            textBox9.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;
        case 'T':
            textBox10.Text = str.Substring(1);
            break;              
    }
}
```

}

=========================

Update: There is further improvement possible with the code block:
The idea is to use Controls.Find to find a textbox by name. You need form the charset exactly according the order that you want to show in the text-boxes:

```
    private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string originalText = textBox11.Text;
        string[] splitString = originalText.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

        String charset = "NGXYIJAHKFTMC";

        foreach(String str in splitString)
        {
            ((TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + charset.IndexOf(str[0]), true)).Text = str.Substring(1);;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: @ACUTALLY THERE IS NO SPACE BETWEEN CHARACTERS.. SORRY ABOUT THAT `N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0`

Comment: Even if there is no space it should work..
Just change the line:
string[] splitString = originalText.Split(new Char[] { 'N', 'G', 'X', 'Y', 'I', 'J', 'A', 'H', 'K', 'F', 'T', 'M', 'C' });

The ordering here does not matter

Comment: That was a perfect one.. when i gave spacing it worked.. tell me how to enter `N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0` .. like this

Comment: Now its showing error  `switch (str[0])` in Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: It may happen if any splitted item is null. You can have a check before calling str[0]..
But remember the charset must be perfect way

Comment: I enter three different types of textess.. in the textbox11.. first type `N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0` Second type `N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0J23.55A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0`. Third type `N14G73X315.2Y83.7J40.0A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0`

Comment: Which code block are you using? I have two blocks.. first one or second one?

Comment: i am trying the  first one.. i tried second one .. its showing..  `Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'`

Comment: Ok forget about the second one.. 
For the first one, just use a check before applying case:

If(str == null || str.Length == 0) continue;

Comment: same error i am getting `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: No.. not like this
I have updated my answer.. check the first one..
If this one does not work we can discuss in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60856/discussion-between-stacy-kebler-and-masum7).

Answer (score 0):

first   of all , i  believe you should really learn to use your debugger.

I am  not  sure how you can get the  results you get,  as first index in the  array  is 0,  not 1.
So splitString[1] could  never be 14.

You probably have something prior to  N  maybe a tab or a blank.

Then after removing J  from string the resulting array  becomes smaller.

[14,73,315.2,83.7,40.0,0.0,3,75,11,5,0,0.0]

If you count the elements, the last  one is [11] ,  so  splitString[12] throws an exception.

Sorry ,  i  am  not  sure  how it should work  at  all.

Comment: THIS is my string entering in textbox... `N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0`. So tell me what i should do please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you...  It will actually work regardless of the order, spacing or whatever between the letters you supply...  Add more if you need to...

```
string yourLetters = "NGXYIJAHKTFMC";
string[] parts = new string[13];
string yourText = textBox11.Text;
int p = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < yourText.Length; i++)
{
    if (yourLetters.Contains(yourText.Substring(i, 1)))
    {
        p++;
        parts[p] = "";
    }
    else
        parts[p] += yourText.Substring(i, 1);
}

// Now, throw the parts into the textboxes
textBox1.Text = parts[0];
textBox2.Text = parts[1];
textBox3.Text = parts[2];
textBox4.Text = parts[3];
textBox5.Text = parts[4];
textBox6.Text = parts[5];
textBox7.Text = parts[6];
textBox8.Text = parts[7];
textBox9.Text = parts[8];
textBox10.Text = parts[9];
```